# Cannot create backup from a database because backup file doesn't exist "Cannot open the backup media"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a backup of my database.

I'm running this SQL statement:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [\\SRV2016\ODSI\BASEDONNEESPJFDB\PJFDB\DATABASE.MDF] 
TO DISK= 'C:\Users\ccadetto\Desktop\PJFDB-Code\PJDB\bin\Debug\bddbackup\Database.bak'
```

I get this error:

> Unable to open backup media 'C:\Users\ccadetto\Desktop\PJFDB-Code\PJDB\bin\Debug\bddbackup\Database.bak'. Error 3(The specified path cannot be found.) of the operating system.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, Status 1, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE ended abnormally.

I tried to create the `Database.bak` file but same error.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I doubt that the SQL Server Service Account has access to the `Users` directory on your PC, nor should it. Back up to somewhere that the account has access to. Don't forgot, the path is from the perspective of the host SQL Server is on too, not you; `C:\ ` means the root of `C:` on the host SQL Server is installed on, not the root of `C:` on your local machine. *(Also, is your database **really** called "`\\SRV2016\ODSI\BASEDONNEESPJFDB\PJFDB\DATABASE.MDF`"? I **really** hope not.)*

Comment: Yes it's the name… A service provider manages our databases and fcked up when he create this one

Comment: I really suggest fixing that name... That will probably cause you far too many problems down the line.

Comment: Can i create the backup on a local directory of the user ?

Comment: *"Can i create the backup on a local directory of the user ?"* To quote my opening statement: "I doubt that the SQL Server Service Account has access to the `Users` directory on your PC, **nor should it.**" It *can*, but don't.

Comment: The backup is created **by the account** which runs SQL Server - that's typically not *your* own account! You need to store the backup file into a folder where that SQL Server account has access to - `C:\tmp`, or any specifically created folder - but certainly **not** into a system-protected folder like `C:\program files` , or a user-specific folder like `C:\users\ccadetto\ :....`

Comment: Ok thank you for yours answers

Comment: Based on my research,I find that we may not have access to backup database on c drive.
Therefore, I suggest that you can move your current project to other drive and change the backup path.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\ccadetto... is relative to a current user, and this current user is probably you.

SQL Server is a service running under another specific user (a Windows service account) and off course does not have any access to your private files for security reasons….

Another complementary reason can be that SQL Server is running on another machine than your desktop PC and has no access to your drives !

A +

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could retrieve this backup locally in order to use the DB outside the network ?